# pyvenv - Why provide access to the system-wide python executable and standard library?

Tags: python

When I create a virtual environment with `pyvenv`, the virtual environment's `python` executable is symlinked to the system-wide installation and consequently, I can access the system-wide standard library. 
Why is this? 
Isn't the whole point of a virtual environment to hedge against API changes in modules? 
Can't changes in the standard library break an application, too?

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/

Comment: @martineau: I was expecting it to provide a **completely** isolated environment.

Comment: @warwaruk: Thanks, I had already read that link. But it only mentions that _copying the whole standard library is not a lightweight solution_. But as far as I can tell I would gain the advantage of an isolated installation.

Comment: @Aton: What I meant was since, generally speaking, python applications don't specify exactly what environment they expect or require, the best that any virtual environment facility can do is make a different version and/or configuration appear to be the one installed globally.

Answer (score 2):

"Isn't the whole point of a virtual environment to hedge against API changes in modules?" You are right. But API changes in the packages added to the site-packages/dist-packages. Not the standard library.
The idea of a virtual environment is for you to set up a library of distributed packages that you want to use together under a certain environment while maintaining the integrity of your standard library. You would want to do this if, for example, you want different versions (or combinations) of these distributed packages to be run in different scenarios without conflicts with other versions. That way, each virtual environment links to the same standard library and you can be sure that the programs executed in an environment have access to a certain version (or even set) of packages that you have decided to keep in that environment.